# VW Mk1 Golf - Best way to clean injectors that are free from the engine block?

Tags: fuel-system, vw, golf, fuel-injection

I'm replacing the O-rings on my injectors (Mk1 Golf - K-Jet mechanical injection) and so will have them free from the engine block. I thought I should clean them at the same time.

***Is there some chemical or product I can soak or rinse the injectors in to clean them? Or do I have to run something through them with pressure?***

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Best bet is take them to a shop which can clean them. They'll also flow bench them to ensure they are working correctly and that they are all within tolerance.

Comment: I second what @Paulster2 wrote. Its better to have them cleaned and flow tested to make sure they are in good condition. It usually runs at about $10 per injector.

Comment: @racefever  Do you have a professional methodology you employ to perform these types of tasks?